# installing a package inside python script without user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, dnf

I want to install a package (dnf install package) through python using subprocess. While installing the package the terminal will ask for a Y/N. mine is an automation script and it should directly use y without user input. how to pass the 'Y' parameter without user input.

Comment: Not a real programming question, more about using commandline tools. Check the help of your tool for an argument to skip the prompt or alternatively use a pipe from the `yes` command (`man yes`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your install code, but something like below would work.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["dnf", "install", "packagename", "-y"])
```

For example, I can list files by

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package using the os. system() function. Just use the code below.

```
import os

def install_package(pkg_name):
    os.system(f'dnf install {pkg_name} -y')
```

Well, I think with this snippet you will be able to install a package within your code.